# Python wrapper for MySQL configuration tables

Tags: python, mysql

I have a set of configuration tables I would like to wrap with python classes.

Tables:

1. tbl_counties
2. tbl_cities
3. tbl_streets

Each city has country_id it belongs to. Same for street with city.

I would like to create 3 python classes that will represent the data in the tables above:
1. Countries
2. Cities
3. Streets

I would like each column in the tables above to be translated to a member variable of the relevant class, such that I would be able to write something like in python:

```
print city.name
```

Anyone knows about some module that implements something that can help me with the task above?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Dig into the object that comes back from your connection API. It probably has a list of columns that you can use to build a `namedtuple`, and then you can create an instance of the named tuple with the data. Alternatively, look into an ORM like SQLAlchemy (although I think that's probably heavier than you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I implemented such a class by myself using python's **setattr** function.